# Is it possible to configure number of slots in a Redis cluster? (cluster mode enabled)

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

According to Redis cluster [specification](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec), a Redis cluster has 16384 slots. I was wondering if any one has successfully tried configuring a Redis cluster to use a different number of slots.

The context of my question is: I have an application that's backed by a cluster-mode Redis cluster. The application sends many multi-get operations to Redis (using MGET command). In cluster mode, MGET is only supported for keys that belong to the same slot, so keys passed into the multi-get operation needs to be grouped by slot, and one MGET command is issued per involved slot.

The number of keys involved in MGET is always much less than 16384, worst case is ~2000 keys, which means most of the multi-get operations will ends up with hundreds of MGET commands with a single key each.

For slots that are on the same node, I can pipeline multiple MGETs to improve performance. But I've been wondering if I can avoid this problem completely by configuring a much lower slot number.

For example, if the number of slots is 128, with a multi-get operation containing 1024 keys (assume these keys are distributed over 128 slots perfectly evenly), it will end up with 128 MGET commands with 8 keys each.

If I group these by nodes and pipeline them, I think the performance will be better than using 16384 slots (1024 perfectly-evenly distributed keys will result in 1024 MGET commands with single key each)

Comment: Redis (including cluster mode) is open source https://github.com/redis/redis/. You can just pull the code and make your own version.

Answer (score 0):

As @sazzad noted, the number of slots is hardcoded (see `cluster.h:#define CLUSTER_SLOTS`) in Redis. It can't be changed by any means other than modifying and recompiling Redis (nor would I recommend using such an untested build).

As for the question itself, are you optimizing something real or is it just for fun? Although `MGET` is more efficient than just `GET`s, as long as you pipeline the batch responsibly the difference usually doesn't matter. The cluster clearly states that it is a subset of Redis, and as such multi-key operations behave differently. On the other hand, the way to squeeze more performance in the cluster is by adding nodes and spreading the load.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.
from what I've read it seems like it's hardcoded and cannot be configured.

I want to be able to have the ability to tune the params for performance. Ideally the maximum perf should be achieved with a slot size comparable to the avg number of keys in a MGET request.